# How to add value in multi dimensions dictionary?

Tags: python, django

I have a column in MySQL "abc" contains data => demo1, demo1, demo2, demo2 and another column name value data =>  abc1, abc2, abc3, abc4 how to convert that into a dictionary like

```py
    {
       'demo1': {'abc1', 'abc2'},
       'demo2' : {'abc3', 'abc4'}

    }
```

```py
branch_array = {}

for branch in get_branch:
        branch_array[branch.abc].append( branch.value)

for branch in get_branch:
        branch_array[branch.abc] = branch.value
```

But nothing worked properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also achieve that with a basic dictionary thanks to `setdefault` method

```
branch_array = {}
for branch in get_branch:
    branch_array.setdefault(branch.abc, []).append(branch.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the thing you are calling `branch_array = {}` is really a dictionary, not an array.  For this answer I used a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which is a specialized dictionary that will create default values for missing keys.

```
import collections

branch_d = collections.defaultdict(set)
for branch in get_branch:
    branch_d[branch.abc].add(branch.value)
```